# How to delay hibernation after sleep in Mac mini?

Tags: sleep-wake, mac-mini, macos, hibernate

When I press a power button on my Mac mini, it goes to sleep mode and when I press it again, it turns on very quickly. However, after a longer sleep, it hibernates. How can I make this delay longer?

I know that I have tu use `pmset` but I don't know how exactly. Should I change the `standbydelay`?

My current config:

```
Last login: Wed Oct 23 08:52:38 on ttys000
Mac-mini-Pawel:~ pmichna$ pmset -g 
Active Profiles:
AC Power        -1*
Currently in use:
 standby              0
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 womp                 1
 autorestart          0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 darkwakes            0
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            0
 sleep                0 (sleep prevented by mds, storeagent, storeagent, storeagent, storeagent, AddressBookSour, UserEventAgent)
 autopoweroffdelay    14400
 hibernatemode        0
 autopoweroff         1
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         10
 standbydelay         4200
```

I use OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switch from sleep to hibernate after set time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82683/switch-from-sleep-to-hibernate-after-set-time)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can increase the standbydelay value:

```
sudo pmset -a standbydelay 18000
```

The value is in seconds, so 18000 is 5 hours. `sudo pmset -a standby 0` would disable standby mode completely.

See `man pmset`:

```
standby causes kernel power management to automatically hibernate a
machine after it has slept for a specified time period. This saves power
while asleep. This setting defaults to ON for supported hardware. The
setting standby will be visible in pmset -g if the feature is supported
on this machine.

standby only works if hibernation is turned on to hibernatemode 3 or 25.

standbydelay specifies the delay, in seconds, before writing the hiberna-
tion image to disk and powering off memory for Standby.
```

Standby mode is also documented in http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4392.