# How to hibernate the Mac after sleep after a set time?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, hibernate

I have these settings on my MacBook with Catalina:

System-wide power settings:

```
Currently in use:
 standbydelaylow      10800
 standby              1
 womp                 1
 halfdim              1
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 proximitywake        1
 powernap             1
 gpuswitch            2
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 standbydelayhigh     86400
 sleep                5
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         5
 tcpkeepalive         1
 highstandbythreshold 50
 acwake               0
 lidwake              1
```

and what I want to achieve is to enter hibernation after an amount of time of "sleep" (after sleeping for 15 minutes for example), like some Linux distro do. I'm new to macOS and what I know is that `hibernatemode 3` means

> The system will wake from memory, unless a power loss forces it to restore from hibernate image.

but I  think I need to leave `hibernatemode 3` and change `standbydelaylow` and `standbydelayhigh` values. Am i correct? These settings are for ac and battery mode or I need to change for these different states? And closing the lid the MacBook goes to sleep immediately?

Comment: [How to add hibernate mode to MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126669/how-to-add-hibernate-mode-to-macbook-pro?rq=1) and [Difference between autopoweroff and standby in pmset
Ask Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/113954/difference-between-autopoweroff-and-standby-in-pmset?rq=1) and [Switch from sleep to hibernate after set time](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82683/switch-from-sleep-to-hibernate-after-set-time?rq=1) can answer your question

Comment: I hope this answers your question. [Do MacBooks have a true "Hibernate" option?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/51725/do-macbooks-have-a-true-hibernate-option)